# How to access variables inside regex statements? c# 4.0

Tags: c#, regex, string, foreach, statements

I have looked everywhere, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make a variable inside a regex statement be accessible from elsewhere.

If someone could help that would be amazing!
Here is the code:

```
string strRegex = @"(regexstring)";

        RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
        string strTargetString = str9

        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
        {
            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
```

Here is the problem     -->             . . ..................
                  string str5 = myMatch.ToString();

```
            }
```

webBrowser1.navigate(str5);  <-- This doesnt work

How Do I access the string str5? outside of the loop? Please Help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the variable *outside* the loop, it needs to be *declared* outside the loop. However, you then need to consider:

- What do you want to happen if there weren't any matches?
- What do you want to happen if there were multiple matches?

You'll need to assign a variable to it outside the loop as otherwise when you try to *read* the variable, the compiler will complain because it's not definitely assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
string str5 = myMatch.Value;
webBrowser1.navigate(str5);
```